# How to estimate a nested logit model using mlogit in R in the case of panel data and degenerate branche?

Tags: panel-data, nested-data, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling, mlogit

I'm using a Discrete Choice Experiment.

I have 9 choice sets with 3 alternatives (2 alternatives and an opt-out), the alternatives are described with 4 attributes.

I want to use a nested logit model where the opt-out is in one nest and the 2 alternatives in the other nest.

```
Nested <- mlogit(Y~  0+ X1+ X2+ X3+ X4+ gender + Age, data=mydata, nests = list(choice=c('1','2'), nochoice=c('3')), un.nest.el = TRUE )
```

However I receive an error message!

I tried to estimate the model in two steps (lower and upper model). However, I obtain the (iv) parameter higher than 1 (iv = 1,1)!

What I am I doing wrong? Is it because I have panel data and the choice between alternatives depend only on the characteristics of individual?